# Run tail command as background process in Python

Tags: python, subprocess, command, tail

I have file named **test.py** and I am trying to run below command as a background process as part of this script

```
"tail -n0 -f debug.log"
```

Also, I want this process to end as soon as test.py execution is completed.
However, I can't get this to working. I have tried below code but  tail command not exiting even after main script is completed.
I am new Python, can someone help me do this clean way ?

```
pro = subprocess.Popen(["tail", "-n0", "-f", log_file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
for line in pro.stdout:
    print(line)
os.killpg(os.getpgid(pro.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
```

Comment: The OS will implement buffering between your Python process and the subprocess. You can get around that with `bufsize=1`. I'll try to find an appropriate duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I used it once before, so I can't remember exactly, but I think I exiting 'subprocess.Popen' using 'with'. I'm not sure, but I recommend giving it a try.

```
with subprocess.Popen(["tail", "-n0", "-f", log_file], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT) as pro:
    for line in pro.stdout:
        print(line)
```

Comment: it's not working, unable to stop the process when main script execution completes :(